# Windows partition is no longer detectable, how can i fix this?

Tags: partitioning, debian, uefi, windows-11, lvm

Long story short: I bought this new flamboyant pc with Windows 11 preinstalled on it, and I wanted to set up a dual boot with Debian.

I'm not a Debian pro (more familiar with Ubuntu), so i tried quite a few time before understanding how to setup Deb installation without issues.

Everything ready to go, I decided to move Windows & reserved partition on the last half of SSD, without making a backup or recovery device (I know, ya shouldn't did that), and with the first half i encrypted the partition and set up the lvm containing Debian.

Once the installation was finished, Debian worked perfectly, but I could no longer login to Win. I'm quite a noob, so I thought it would have been easy to set the EFI partition to find and run Windows Boot Manager, but unfortunately, this wasn't the case.

PS: The initial Windows Partition was protected with Bitlocker, if that's relevant.

Searching on the internet for solutions, i tried the most commons. I made an USB recovery device, and tried Startup Repair on Advance Options: "Startup Repair couldn't repair your pc". Very well.
Then I tried with the command prompt from recovery USB:

1. diskpart only detects the USB storage, dunno why or how
2. `bootsect /nt60 all /mbr`

```
Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode.

C: (\\?\Volume{54ee0b10-8f1c-11ed-b2ea-806e6f6e6963})

    Successfully updated FAT32 fylesystem bootcode.

\??\PhysicalDrive0

    Successfully updated disk bootcode

Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.
```

`bcdboot c:\windows /s c:` or `bcdboot \\?\Volume{54ee0b10-8f1c-11ed-b2ea-806e6f6e6963} /s c:` or `c:\windows /s \\?\Volume{54ee0b10-8f1c-11ed-b2ea-806e6f6e6963}`

```
Failure when attempting to copy boot files.
```

3. Using Debian, I tried to copy the directory C:\Windows\Boot\EFI into /boot/efi/EFI/microsoft/
   then, in the shell

```
root@omega:~#efibootmgr --create --label 'windows' --disk /dev/nvme0n1 --part 2 --loader 'boot/efi/EFI/microsoft/EFI/bootmgfw.efi
Bootcurrent 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0003
Boot0001* debian
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0000* windows
```

but still, when i get into the UEFI Firmware i cannot see the boot entry

Trying to create the boot entry manually from firmware gets me only an error page

```
Windows Failed to start. A recent hardware of software change might be the cause.
Blah blah blah, try to fix it with Boot Repair, blah blah blah

File: \EFI|Microsoft\Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this issue without formatting the entire SSD and start from scratch?

Sorry if I missed important pieces of information, and thanks for your patience.

Comment: I am guessing you didn’t suspend or disable BitLocker before you performed any of these operations?

Comment: If you are trying your hand at something, it is faster and safer to use a Virtual Machine. That will not break your host machine

Comment: It may be easier to reinstall Windows from ISO than fix it, particularly with the complication of BitLocker. Consider this a learning experience.

Comment: @Ramhound I fear you're guessing right, I will wait another day if there is anyone who has encountered this problem before, otherwise I will reset the SSD and restart from scratch, thanks evertone, it surely has been a learning (and frustrating) experience. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this issue before; it has to do with majorly shrinking a volume when there is a OS on it. Sometimes you can get away with it but with Bitlocker you can't because it requires the original volume to be untouched and complete (obviously which you changed by partitioning the drive).

If you had important files on the machine, I suggest making a bootable usb with ubuntu on it and attempting to recover your files by mounting your C:// drive from Windows.

Long story short you will have to end up having to reinstall Windows because you corrupted the files on the Windows volume making the OS unable to boot.

Hope this helps you.